# What is the meaning of set -e -o pipefail?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, scripting

What is the meaning of the below command? I am new in shell scripting.

```
set -e -o pipefail
```

Answer (score 39):

End the script immediately if any command or pipe exits with a non-zero status.

I don't usually use these two flags, but if you're just getting started shell scripting, this would be like turning on warnings or strict mode in other languages.

> `-e`
>
> Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.

> `-o <option-name>`
>
> Sets the `<option-name>` flag. In this case, it sets the `pipefail` option.

> `pipefail`
>
> If set, causes the pipeline to return the exit status of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status.
> It returns zero if all commands in the pipeline exit successfully.
> This option is disabled by default.

Comment: and `-o` stays for `--option-name`.